# Is the WER (winqual) web service API documented anywhere

Tags: winqual, windows-error-reporting

I can find a few examples of accessing WER data through a SOAP API such as this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2010/05/14/winqual-web-services-with-windows-powershell.aspx

Is the API they're calling documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CodePlex project... http://wer.codeplex.com/releases/view/12825 that has sample code and a whitepaper available.